# how to overcome this error?

Tags: android, sms, syntax-error

i used a code for sending sms through android app.

```
android.telephony.SmsManager sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

i get a error in the second line as as

> Syntax error on token "(", delete this token
>       - Syntax error on token "null", invalid VariableDeclarator
>       - Syntax error on tokens, ConstructorHeaderName expected 
>        instead

Using android sdk version 2.3.3 API 10.

Answer (score 1):

change your code as:

```
android.telephony.SmsManager sms = android.telephony.SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

and best way is:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
```

and press **<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>** from keyboard for importing all necessary packages

Comment: i imported the right package.and still get error in the second line of code.

Comment: @user1870724 : try `smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);` line

Comment: @user1870724 : and make sure you ahve imported `import android.telephony.SmsManager;`

Comment: @user1870724 : you have some other issue because code is right can u post more code for this means full class where you are using this code

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/43/captureszd.png/ this is a snapshot of my code.i have not got enough space to post here.

Comment: i found where is problem just put these two lines inside onCreate of Activity after setContentView(R.layout.main); or inside onClick(View v) of button

Comment: thanks a lot.but i ve messed up in declaring the right scope now.thanks again.